# Crockford's module for secure objects

Tags: javascript

I understand there's loads of questions and documentation around "Javascript: The Good Parts" but I'm trying to understand the meaning of a sentence in the book and can't quite get it. In the pages 41-42 he defines the serial_maker function:

```
var serial_maker = function (  ) {

// Produce an object that produces unique strings. A
// unique string is made up of two parts: a prefix
// and a sequence number. The object comes with
// methods for setting the prefix and sequence
// number, and a gensym method that produces unique
// strings.

    var prefix = '';
    var seq = 0;
    return {
        set_prefix: function (p) {
            prefix = String(p);
        },
        set_seq: function (s) {
            seq = s;
        },
        gensym: function (  ) {
            var result = prefix + seq;
            seq += 1;
            return result;
        }
    };
};

var seqer = serial_maker();
seqer.set_prefix('Q');
seqer.set_seq(1000);
var unique = seqer.gensym(); // unique is "Q1000"
```

And then he says:

> The methods do not make use of *this* and *that*. As a result, there is no way to compromise the *sequer*. It isn't posible to get or change the *prefix* or *seq* except as permitted by the methods

How should I use *this* and/or *that* to break that encapsulation? I can't see it

Thanks

Comment: His point is that the way the code is written, the actual storage is protected in the closure and cannot be modified by anything other than those exported functions.

Comment: Contrast that with code that stored the `prefix` and `seq` values as ordinary object properties.

Comment: Yes, I can see that the closure encapsulates it but not sure why the reference to this and that

Comment: I don't know why he mentioned `that` because it doesn't mean anything. He mentioned `this` because the `this` reference would be how code that stored the internal values on the object would work.

Comment: Before arrow functions were introduced, a common way to ensure that a function defined as a method could still access the context where it was defined was to write `var that = this;` before the function definition, and then use `that` where you would use `this` in an arrow function. If that doesn't make sense, I can give examples in an answer.

Comment: But even if you "capture" the context with the *that* you would still need to go through the methods, right? so you are not exposing the properties. Same question remains, to me, on @Pointy comment how would you use this that exposes them if you just return the methods

Comment: The whole point of the example in the book is that you cannot get to the protected variables in the closure.

Comment: Yes, and that I see it clearly. Maybe I was over analyzing the subsequent sentence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the variation below:

```
var serial_maker = function () {
    return {
        prefix: '',
        seq: 0,

        set_prefix: function (p) {
            this.prefix = String(p);
        },
        set_seq: function (s) {
            this.seq = s;
        },
        gensym: function (  ) {
            var result = this.prefix + this.seq;
            this.seq += 1;
            return result;
        }
    };
};
```

Now, the intended use of the sequer is the following:

```
var sequer = serial_maker();
sequer.set_prefix('right');
sequer.set_seq(1000);
```

However, in the version I posted above, you could also do this:

```
var sequer = serial_maker();
sequer.prefix = 'wrong';
sequer.seq = -500;
```

Or even this:

```
delete sequer.prefix;
```

Since both `prefix` and `seq` are exposed as properties of the sequer object, and properties in JavaScript are always public. Any code that has access to the object can at least read its properties, and usually modify them as well (unless you use some of the features provided by `Object.defineProperty()`).

As for `that`: before arrow functions were introduced, it was a very common problem that functions defined as methods weren't able to access the context where they were created.

Consider the following example:

```
var ButtonInitializer = {
    message: 'Hello!'

    init: function() {
        for (let button of document.querySelectorAll('button')) {
            button.onclick = function() {
                alert(this.message);
            }
        }
    }
};

ButtonInitializer.init();
```

The object `ButtonInitializer` searches the document for `<button>` elements and sets their `onclick` event listener to display an alert; our intention is to show the message defined in `ButtonInitializer.message`. However, if you run the above code, you'll find that the alert is "`undefined`". This is because the function we assign to `button.onclick` becomes a method of the button, so the `this` keyword inside the function will now refer to the button, and not the `ButtonInitializer`.

Today, we can solve this with an arrow function:

```
button.onclick = () => {
    alert(this.message);
}
```

Arrow functions don't have their own `this` scope, so the alert will display `ButtonInitializer.message`, as we meant. Before arrow functions were introduced, this was a common workaround:

```
var that = this;
button.onclick = function() {
    alert(that.message);
}
```

This technique was used very commonly together with closures, and allowed a limited implementation of "private" members that the object's methods could access, but weren't directly visible from outside code.

Comment: Thanks, Mate. I see your point but the thing is that you have changed as well the return to return the properties. My question was more in the sense that the encapsulation comes naturally from just returning the functions that are closures but could not see any usage of this and/or that which would break it

Comment: The usage that would break it is what I wrote at the beginning. In Crockford's implementation, it's impossible to break the encapsulation, precisely because he never uses `this`, only the enclosed local variables.

Comment: Actually, my comment on your answer was due to the fact that you needed extra refactor (in this case, changing the return to return the properties as well) but you are right, and even more even if you don't return them you can still access them http://jsbin.com/kiyequsedu/edit?js,console

Answer (score 2):

There are two popular ways of creating objects from a function in JavaScript:

- The `factory` pattern
- The `constructor` pattern (Better illustrated using ES6 `class`)

**The `factory` Pattern**

In this example, he is using and referring to the `factory` pattern, which does not make use of the `new` keyword and also does not create a `this` binding on the newly created object. It only creates a new object and returns it as a value of the function expression, thus why it is called a factory.

Factory functions are the best way to create true object private attributes in JavaScript, thus encapsulation using closure. Because there is no `this` binding, you cannot access the variables `prefix` and `seq` that are encapsulated within the factory function. Using this pattern is the only way to create fully-private encapsulated object "property" in JavaScript (in comparison to Java's use of `private`.)

> How should I use this and/or that to break that encapsulation?

You would re-factor that code using the *`Constructor` Pattern* (Make it into a constructor) which would look like this (using ES6):

```
class SerialMaker {
    // Creates a `this` binding to the instance of the class
    // No actual encapsulation on the private properties
    constructor () {
        // PSEUDO-PRIVATE PROPERTIES
        this.__prefix__ = '';
        this.__seq__ = 0;
        // METHODS
        this.set_prefix: function (p) {
            this.__prefix__ = String(p);
        };
        this.set_seq: function (s) {
            this.__seq__ = s;
        };
        gensym: function (  ) {
            var result = this.__prefix__ + this.__seq__;
            this.__seq__ += 1;
            return result;
        };
    }
```

Now, you can create new object using the `new` operator

```
var seqer = new SerialMaker(); // Calls the constructor and creates a new instance object
seqer.set_prefix('Q'); // Set on this instance only: this.__prefix__
seqer.set_seq(1000); // Set on this instance only: this.__seq__
var unique = seqer.gensym(); // unique is "Q1000"
```

Same thing up to this point, but the problem is...

```
sequer.__prefix__ // => 'Q' // What??? This was supposed to be private!
sequer.__seq__ = 2000 // Works with no error
```

... **the encapsulation is completely broken**. The seqer is compromised.